# Filter by key in (key, val) pair using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I ahave the following data:

```
[
  {
    "rub": {
      "item1": 979,
      "item2": 32,
      "item3": 845
    },
    "shop": "shop1",
  },
  {
    "rub": {
      "item232": 84,
      "item213": 348
    },
    "shop": "shop2"
  }
]
```

I try to filter it in a table by key using `ng-model`. But it isn't filtering at all.

```
<table class="table ng-cloak" ng-repeat="rub in rubs | filter:isActive" ng-if='isActive'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Товар" ng-model="rub.rub[key]">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Товар</th>
        <th>Число</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='(key, val) in rub.rub'>
        <td>{{ $index }}</td>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ val }}</td>
      </tr>                  
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My controller:

```
curryControllers.controller('CurryRubricsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $route) {
    $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
    $http.get('cities.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.cities = data;
    $http.get('json/shop_data.json').success(function(data2) {
      $scope.rubs = data2;

      $scope.isActive = function(item) {
    return item.shop === $scope.cityId;
  };
  });
  });
```

I've tried to add `$scope.searchRub = ''` to the controller and put a form in the html template.

```
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск" ng-model="searchRub">

      </div>      
    </div>
  </form>
```

Added this 'searchRub' filter here : `<td> {{ key | filter:searchRub }} </td>`
It didn't help either.

Comment: there is not presence of "link" key in your object, so it will always return false\

Comment: @Devidas, sorry, I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the search box to model an independent value which you can then use to filter, rather than trying to model it to the key of an object that you are already using.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Товар" ng-model="search”>
```

There are a number of ways to use this value to filter, but the easiest is with an ng-show:

```
<tr ng-repeat='(key, val) in rub.rub' ng-show="search ? search===key : true">
```

Here’s the plunk.  I’ve hardcoded the cityId to avoid using routeParams for the demo.

https://plnkr.co/edit/sI8HAbNKBBJGMx0FediD?p=preview

type "item1" into the search box.

Comment: thanks. Almost. But it shows nothing when input is empty. How to show all table rows if the input field is empty?

Comment: You want to default the ng-show to true if the search is empty.  I have updated the answer and the  Plunk.

Comment: @GerainAnderson, thanks! Is there a way to filter data dynamically without exact match in the input field. I mean, if a user write 'ite' data filter dynamically.

Comment: Sure. You just need to change the expression in the ng-show to something that evaluates to true when you need it.  For complicated situations I would call a function on the server.  For this, just swap the ng-show for `ng-show="search ? key.includes(search) : true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Underscore.js to achieve this,

```
data = [
  {
    "rub": {
      "item1": 979,
      "item2": 32,
      "item3": 845
    },
    "shop": "shop1"
  },
  {
    "rub": {
      "item232": 84,
      "item213": 348
    },
    "shop": "shop2"
  }
]
$scope.specific_key = []
_.filter(data, function(val){$scope.specific_key.push(val['rub'])});
console.log($scope.specific_key);
```

in `$scope.specific_key`, It will return contain keys 'rub' .

Comment: Should I pass `specific_key` to `ng-model` in my input tag?

Comment: Your ng-model confuse me.. from your ng-model,  based on your ng-repeat and your object,  rub.rub[key] doesnot give what you want... clearly what you want in your model ? i understand in your table what you actually want.. clear about ng-model

Comment: you can also pass specific_key 'rub' to your ng-model, based on your data, it should be, ng-model='rub[your_key]'

Comment: @MohideenbinMohammed, I want any user can filter the table as he wishes by 'items'.
'isActive filter' has already filtered the shop before the page is loaded.
If any user wants to find 'item1' he writes it in input and get the result.

I try to do it like here: [link](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/AmFLE) but it doesn't work.